# Exibir dados via ajax/jquery do banco de dados

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, banco-de-dados, apache-cordova

Eu necessito exibir os dados relacionados aos usuários que estão em uma tabela no banco de dados, porém esses dados não recebem uma entrada (input no form de login), não são preenchidos. Eu apenas quero dar um select nos valores, e exibir eles na página html, na página da conta do usuário, após o login ser validado. Estou usando localStorage mas não estou conseguindo retornar os valores corretamente. Pois não posso usar o .val() nestes valores, pois necessitaria de um input, e esses dados devem ser ''capturados'' através do nome do usuário.  Estou usando Cordova por isso não posso usar php diretamente na página HTML, há de ser através de requisições

Toda ajuda é bem vinda!

`` SELECT `saldo`, `lucro` FROM users WHERE `nomecompleto` = '$nomecompleto'; ``

o saldo não retorna nada na página html, e o lucro retorna undefined.

segue o código ajax/jquery:

login.js

```
$(document).ready(function()

        {
            // call api to handle with registration.

            var url = "/log_users.php";

            $(".btn").btn().on("change", function()

            {
                var nomecompleto = $.trim($("#nomecompleto").val());
                var cpf= $.trim($("#cpf").val());
                var password= $.trim($("#password").val());
                var saldo = $(this).val();
                var lucro = $(this).val();

                $("#status").text("Autenticando acesso.");


                var loginString = "nomecompleto="+nomecompleto+"&cpf="+cpf+"&password="+password+"&login=";

                $.ajax(

                {
                    type: "POST", 
                    crossDomain: true, 
                    cache: false,
                    url: url,
                    datatype: 'jsonp',
                    crossDomain: true,
                    data: loginString,
                    success: function(data){
                        if(data == "success") {
                            $("#status").html("Olá" +nomecompleto);
                            localStorage.loginstatus = "true";
                            localStorage.nomecompleto = nomecompleto;
                            localStorage.saldo = saldo; //aqui está o erro...
                            localStorage.lucro = lucro; // e aqui..
                            window.location.href = "welcome.html?id=" +nomecompleto;
                        }
                        else if(data == "error")
                        {
                            $("#status").text("A requisição de login falhou. Tente novamente mais tarde.");
                            alert("A requisição de login falhou. Tente novamente mais tarde." +status);
                            localStorage.loginstatus = "false";
                            window.location.href = "login.html";


                        }
                    }
                });
            });

        $("#nome1").html(localStorage.nomecompleto);
        $("#saldo1").html(localStorage.saldo);
        $("#lucro1").html(localStorage.lucro);

        });
```

log_users.php

```
<?php

    include "config.php";

    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    header('Content-Type: application/javascript');

    session_start();

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    $con = mysqli_connect("$server","$user","$pass","$database") or die("connection error");


    $nomecompleto = $_POST['nomecompleto'];
    $cpf = $_POST['cpf'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $saldo = $_GET['saldo'];
    $lucro = $_GET['lucro'];

    if(isset($_POST['register']))

    {   
        $register = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email`='$email'"));

        if($register == 0)

        {
            $insert = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `users` (`email`,`password`) VALUES ('$email','$password')");

            if($insert)
                echo "success";

            else
                echo "error";
        }

        else if($register != 0)

            echo "exist";
    }

    else if(isset($_POST['login']))

    {
        //$login = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email`='$email' AND`password`='$password'"));

        $login = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `nomecompleto`, `cpf`, `password` FROM `users` WHERE `nomecompleto`='$nomecompleto' AND `cpf`='$cpf' AND `password`= '$password'"));
        $saldo =  mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `saldo`, `lucro` FROM `users` WHERE `nomecompleto` = '$nomecompleto'"));
        if($login != 0  && $saldo != 0)

            echo "success";

    }    else

            echo "error";

    }

    mysqli_close($con);


?>
```

conta.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="pt-br">

<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>


    <title>Bem vindo à sua conta</title>

    <style>
 body {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
 }



 #background
{
     left: 0px;
     top: 0px;
     position: relative;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     width: 100%;
     height: auto;
     overflow: hidden;
     z-index:0;
     background-color: #707070;
    }


</style>

</head>

<div id="background">
<body>

    <header style="text-align: center; background-color: white; height: 80px;">
        <img style="height: 76px; width: 52px; margin-left: -20px; margin-right: 0; left: 26px; float: left; position: relative; top: 2px;" src="logo.png">

<h1>OLÁ

    <div id="nome1">
    </div></h1>
    </header>

    <main style="text-align: center;">

  <article>


     <img style="height: 800px; width: auto;" align="left" src="Retngulo3.png">

     <img style="height: 800px; width: auto;"  align="right" src="Retngulo3.png">

     </article>


     <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br />
     <p style="color: white; text-align: center; font-size: 14px;">SEU SALDO ATUAL É DE: </p><div style="text-align:center; font-size: 14px; border: 3px solid white; width: 213px; height: 38px; border-radius: 14px; background-color:#707070; display: inline-block;" id="saldo1"><br /></div>

     <br><br><br><br>
     <p style="color: white; text-align: center; font-size: 14px;">COM LUCRABILIDADE DE: </p><div style="text-align: center; display: inline-block; background: url(Elipse1copiar.png); height: 302px; width: 302px; color: white;" id="lucro1"></div>


        <br><br>

    <a href="simular.html" style="margin-left: -20px; left: 30px;float: left; text-decoration: none; width: 120px; color: white; font-size: 14px; display: inline-block; top: 2px;">SIMULAR</a>
     <a href="retirar.html" style="display: inline-block; margin-right: 0; float: right; width: 100px; color: white; font-size: 14px;  top: 2px;">SOLICITAR</a>




    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
   <!-- <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var saldo = $("#saldo").val();
        $.ajax({

            type: "get",crossDomain: true, cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            url: '/display_info_users.php',
            data: "saldo=" + saldo,
            success: function(data){

                $("#saldo1").html(data.saldo);
            }
        })
    });
</script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="login.js"></script>
    </main>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="pt-br">

<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
                    href="sherlockstyle.css"/>

    <title>Login Usuários</title>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="header">
        <img style="height: 80px; width: 40px;" align="left" src="logo.png">
        <h2>Faça o login</h2>
    </div>

    <main id="form" class="btn">

    <div class="input-group">
    <label>Nome completo: </label>

     <input id="nomecompleto" name="nomecompleto" type="text" placeholder="Nome completo..." /> <br/>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group">

    <label>CPF/CNPJ: </label>



    <input id="cpf" type="cpf" name="cpf" placeholder="CPF/CNPJ" /> <br/>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group">

    <label>Senha: </label>



    <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Senha..." /> <br/>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group">
    <button id="loginButton" class="btn">Login</button>

    <br>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
    <!--<button id="registerButton" class="btn">Registrar</button>-->
    <br>

    <hr>  </div>Status: <p style="text-align: center; color: #3c763d;" id="status"></p></hr>

</main>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="login.js"></script>

     <!--   $(document).ready(function()

        {
            // call api to handle with registration.

            var url = "/log_users.php";

            $("#loginButton").click(function()

            {
                var email= $.trim($("#email").val());
                var password= $.trim($("#password").val());

                $("#status").text("Autenticando acesso.");


                var loginString ="email="+email+"&password="+password+"&login=";

                $.ajax(

                {
                    type: "POST",crossDomain: true, cache: false,
                    url: url,
                    datatype: 'jsonp',
                    crossDomain: true,
                    data: loginString,
                    success: function(data){
                        if(data == "success") {
                            $("#status").html("hello" +email);
                            localStorage.loginstatus = "true";
                            localStorage.email=email;
                            window.location.href = "welcome.html?id=" +email;
                        }
                        else if(data == "error")
                        {
                            $("#status").text("A requisição de login falhou. Tente novamente mais tarde.");
                            alert("A requisição de login falhou. Tente novamente mais tarde." +status);
                            localStorage.loginstatus = "false";
                             window.location.href = "login.html";
                        }
                    }
                });
            });

            $("#registerButton").click(function()

            {
                var email= $.trim($("#email").val());
                var password= $.trim($("#password").val());

                $("#status").text("Configurando conta.");
                var dataString="email="+email+"&password="+password+"&register=";

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",crossDomain: true, cache: false,
                    url: url,
                    data: dataString,
                    success: function(data)

                    {
                        if(data == "success")

                            //email.reset();
                           // password.reset();
                            $("#status").html("Cadastro realizado! Usuário registrado no banco de dados.");

                        else if( data == "exist")
                            $("#status").text("Essas credenciais já estão cadastradas no banco de dados. Verifique.");

                        else if(data == "error")
                            $("#status").text("Registro falhou. Tente novamente mais tarde.");
                    }
                });
            });
        });

    </script>-->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O retorno do ajax post é o que você 'printa' na tela no PHP, por exemplo:

```
$login = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `nomecompleto`, `cpf`, `password` FROM `users` WHERE `nomecompleto`='$nomecompleto' AND `cpf`='$cpf' AND `password`= '$password'"));
$saldo =  mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `saldo`, `lucro` FROM `users` WHERE `nomecompleto` = '$nomecompleto'"));
if($login != 0  && $saldo != 0)    
   echo "success";
}else {  
   echo "error";    
}
```

Nesse trecho você está enviano "success" ou "error". Esses valores são o que você utiliza no objeto data na JQuery.

Para passar os valores você precisa incluir esses valores no retorno, JSON é um caminho, primeiro você passa o resultado para array depois printa o JSON na tela para retorno.

```
        $saldoSql =  mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `saldo`, `lucro` FROM `users` WHERE `nomecompleto` = '$nomecompleto'"));

$emparray = array(); //cria o array
if($login != 0  && $saldo != 0) {
   $emparray['resultado'] = "success"; //na resposta você usa este index para  conferir o resultado

   //preenche o array com os resultados
   //entendi que só existe um linha de saldo, se tiver mais use um 'while'
   $emparray['saldo'] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($saldoSql))
} else {
   $emparray['resultado'] = "error"; //na resposta você usa este index para  conferir o resultado
}

echo json_encode($emparray); //print na tela o JSON
```

No JQuery, você passa o Json para objeto dentro do success do ajax:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( data ); //passa o retorno para objeto
//agora o resultado está no objeto
if(obj.resultado == "success") {
     $("#status").html("Olá" +nomecompleto);
     localStorage.loginstatus = "true";
     localStorage.nomecompleto = nomecompleto; /
     localStorage.saldo = obj.saldo.saldo; //como passamos o resultado para o bjeto saldo usamos desta forma, 'saldo' é o nome da coluna do banco /pelo que entendi 
     localStorage.lucro = obj.saldo.lucro; // e por ai vai
     window.location.href = "welcome.html?id=" + nomecompleto;
   }
   else if(obj.resultado == "error")
   {
      $("#status").text("A requisição de login falhou. Tente novamente mais tarde.");
      alert("A requisição de login falhou. Tente novamente mais tarde." +status);
      localStorage.loginstatus = "false";
      window.location.href = "login.html";
   }
```

só incluir no seu código.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Clareou as ideias. Mas está retornando ```undefined```, só o nome que é exibido corretamente. Não teria que alterar a ```data``` no ajax? Pois é passado os parâmetros apenas do form, não incluí o ```saldo``` e o ```lucro```... tentei usar o .serialize() mas não retornou nenhum dos valores.

Comment: confere se o nome das colunas no banco são estas mesmo, e se o saldo realmente é um objeto, ou array,  tipo saldo[0], saldo[1] etc.

Comment: Sim, sim. Os nomes nas colunas são esses mesmos. E são arrays, assim como todo método $_POST, certo? ```code $nomecompleto = $_POST['nomecompleto'];
    $cpf = $_POST['cpf'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $saldo = $_POST['saldo'];
    $lucro = $_POST['lucro'];```

   Será que não teria que incluir esse ```header```:

   ```header('Content-Type: application/json');``` 

   ao invés do ```header('Content-Type: application/javascript');``` 

   eu vi no site do php, no primeiro comentário: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php

Obrigado desde já!

Comment: E na parte dos parâmetros para o data, há a necessidade de incluir o ```saldo```e o ```lucro```?

```var saldo = $(this).saldo;
    var lucro = $(this).lucro;```

Analisando outros códigos, não notei a inclusão dos valores que não são preenchidos no form...

Comment: Nessa linha `$emparray['saldo'] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($saldoSql))` você inclui o resultado da busca na lista, testa o php e vê se query está retornando, outra coisa faz `console.log(data)` no console do navegador ele vai printar a estrutura da resposta, vê se os resultados estão em algum lugar.

Comment: Tudo certo. Valeu, brother! Abraço